# Create relations in Neo4j graph based on max and min group column value

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a csv file with a structure similar to this.

```
 elementID | groupID | sequence
     abc   |    A    |    0
     dcv   |    A    |    1
     asd   |    B    |    0
     ccc   |    B    |    1
     abc   |    B    |    2
```

and a Neo4j graph where nodes corresponding to `elementID` and `groupID` have already been created with the corresponding IDs.

Now from this csv file I want to create a relationship from each `group` (having the `groupID` indicated in the csv file) to the `element` node (having the `elementID` indicated in the csv file) with label `:STARTS` **if** the  `sequence` value in the corresponding tuple is `0`, with label `:STOPS` **if** the  `sequence` value is the maximum for that group.

To be clearer, considering the rows above the following relations should be created:

```
(A)-[:STARTS]->(abc)
(A)-[:STOPS]->(dcv)
(B)-[:STARTS]->(asd)
(B)-[:STOPS]->(abc)
```

I have tried to create the `:START` relationship with this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS row
UNWIND KEYS(row) AS bid
WITH bid, row
WHERE bid="equence" AND TOINTEGER(row[bid]) = 0
MATCH (t:Group {Id: row.groupID})
MATCH (b:Element {Id: row.elementID})
WITH b, t
MERGE (t)-[:STARTS]->(b);
```

but it seems to take forever.

On the contrary I do not where to start in order to crate the other type of relationship.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the row field by their name, so you don't need the `UNWIND` on keys:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS row
WITH row
WHERE toInteger(row.sequence) = 0
MATCH (t:Group {ID: row.groupID})
MATCH (b:Element {ID: row.elementID})
MERGE (t)-[:STARTS]->(b);
```

Supposing you have the indexes on `:Group(ID)` and `:Element(ID)` it should be reasonably fast.

Use `max` aggregation to find the maximum element and create the relationship, this creates both relationships in single query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/file.csv" as line
WITH line.groupID as groupID, collect({elementID: line.elementID, sequence:toInteger(line.sequence)}) as groupElements,max(toInteger(line.sequence)) as max
UNWIND groupElements as element
MATCH (g:Group {ID:groupID}),(e:Element {ID:element.elementID})
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN element.sequence = 0 THEN [1] ELSE [] END | CREATE (g)-[:STARTS]->(e))
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN element.sequence = max THEN [1] ELSE [] END | CREATE (g)-[:STOPS]->(e))
```

It is using a trick described here:

https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/08/22/neo4j-load-csv-handling-empty-columns/

*Update:* If you have many rows which have sequence other than 0 and max, then you could filter those out by adding

```
WITH element,max,groupID
WHERE element.sequence = 0 OR element.sequence = max
```

just before the `MATCH`, which should avoid index lookups for those rows.

**Update on FOREACH/CASE syntax**: This is a workaround for Cypher's lack of capabilities in this area.

The [CASE expression](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#query-syntax-case) is Cypher's if/then/else condition. However it is an expression (= returns a value) and can't contain write operations. That's what we need the [FOREACH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/foreach/#query-foreach-introduction) for.

```
CASE WHEN element.sequence = 0 THEN [1] ELSE [] END
```

Returns array containing number 1 when the sequence is equal to 0. If the sequence condition is true it will be equivalent to this:

```
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN [1] | CREATE (g)-[:STARTS]->(e))
```

It will execute the part after `|` for each element in the array. The variable is called `ignoreMe` because it is not used. If the condition is false the array is empty so no CREATE statement will be executed.

Comment: It works but I have a few question. I get these two warnings `This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.` and `The execution plan for this query contains the Eager operator, which forces all dependent data to be materialized in main memory before proceeding`.  I guess `collect` is creating a list grouping by `line.groupID` but I do not understand the syntax `FOREACH .. IN CASE WHEN.. THEN[1] ELSE[0] ..END`

Comment: The cartesian product is false positive if your ids are unique. Yes, it needs to load everything into memory for the max aggregation. Regarding the foreach and case syntax see the update.